# Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, ...]]' to type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odata, wcf-data-services

I'm currently trying to return a dbset using OData with Entity Framework through a WCF Service. I'm able to hit the getter on my dbset property in my data context, but when it returns I get the error:

> LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types

Originally I thought this was due to me having nullable foreign keys in my entity models, but I still get the error after removing all nullable int types.

MyDataContext.cs

```
  public class MyDataContext : DbContext, IMyDataContext, IMyDbContextFactory
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Default Constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MyDataContext()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ConnectionString Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="connectionString">Sets the initial connection string</param>
        public MyDataContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString)
        {
            this.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        }

        public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

        #region Global Resources
        public DbSet<MyResource> MyResource{ get; set; }

        #region Ranges
        public DbSet<TheRanges> TheRanges { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TheRangesSub> TheRangesSub { get; set; }

        #region EF Model Configuration

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.RegisterEntityType(typeof(MyResource));
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
}
```

MyResource.cs

```
    [Table("MyResource")]
    [DataServiceKey("Id")]
    public class MyResource
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string MyResource { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public bool SomeStandard { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    }
```

TheRanges.cs

```
    [Table("TheRanges")]
    [DataServiceKey("Id")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public class TheRanges
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int MyResourceId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(MyResourceId))]
        public MyResource MyResource { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int someIntField { get; set; }

        public string LinkId { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

TheRangesSub.cs

```
  [Table("TheRangesSub")]
    [DataServiceKey("Id")]
    public class TheRangesSub
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required] 
        public int TheRangesId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(TheRangesId))]
        public TheRanges TheRanges { get; set; }

        public string FacilityNum { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int SomeOtherInt { get; set; }

        public string LinkId { get; set; } 

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string RangeName { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string CreatedDateTime { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(255)]
        [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = true)]
        public string ModifiedDateTime { get; set; }

        public DateTime Modified { get; set; }

        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    }
```

MyService.cs

```
    [BasicHttpBindingServiceMetadataExchangeEndpoint]
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true)]
    public class MyService : DataService<MyDataContext>
    {
        private SPWeb _web;
        private string connectionString;

        #region Constructor
        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MyService() : base()
        {

        }

        #endregion
        #region Methods

        protected override MyDataContext CreateDataSource()
        {
            return new MyDataContext("MyConnectionString");
        }


        public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
        {
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("TheRanges", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("TheRangesSub", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("MyResource", EntitySetRights.AllRead);
            config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceProtocolVersion.V2;
            config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
        }
        #endregion
```

Let me know if there's naming inconsistencies that happened when I changed names

I have 1 item in my database for MyResource, so I'd like that returned.
The OData query I'm executing is:
http://myurl/MyData.svc/MyResource?$select=Id

The last spot in my code that gets hit when I run the debugger is the "get" on:

```
DbSet<MyResource> MyResource {get; set;}
```

However, this is the current error that I'm getting:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<code/>
<message xml:lang="en-US">An error occurred while processing this request.</message>
<innererror>
<message>
Unable to cast the type 'System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.
</message>
<type>System.NotSupportedException</type>
<stacktrace>
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ValidateAndAdjustCastTypes(TypeUsage toType, TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.GetCastTargetType(TypeUsage fromType, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType, Boolean preserveCastForDateTime)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.CreateCastExpression(DbExpression source, Type toClrType, Type fromClrType)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConvertTranslator.TranslateUnary(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression unary, DbExpression operand)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MemberInitTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MemberInitExpression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConditionalTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConditionalExpression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SelectTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.SerializeResponseBody(RequestDescription description, IDataService dataService)
 at System.Data.Services.DataService`1.HandleRequest()
</stacktrace>
</innererror>
</error>
```

Edit: so by having just the query string "http://myurl/MyData.svc/MyResource? I'm able to retrieve my items from the database, but I'm not able to grab the items using the $select and some attribute due to the unable to cast the type error. I'm able to run $filter and $count on the entities as well. It seems that this is just a $select issue.

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: I'm not sure. The last thing that gets hit when I step through is the "get" on DbSet<MyResource> MyResource { get; set;}. I'll update the question with the OData query I'm using too.

Comment: What if you try to select `Title` instead of `Id`? Do you get an error?

Comment: Interesting, I get a similar error. "Unable to cast System.String to type System.Object'. LINQ to entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: If I use: http://myurl/MyData3.svc/MyResource? Then I get the following xml: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="..." xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">MyResource</title>
  <id>http://myurl/MyData3.svc/MyResource</id>
  <updated>...</updated>
  <author>
    <name />
  </author>
  <link rel="self" title="MyResource" href="MyResource" />
</feed>

Comment: FYI, your title and stack trace don't match the code you're showing since apparently you're showing the code after you removed the nullable keys. I suggest changing the code or the title/stack trace so that they are consistent or you'll get more comments like mine :).

Comment: I still get the nullable error even after removing the nullable keys.